# C++ PlaySound() giving errors

Tags: c++, playsound

I was trying to use the PlaySound(); function in C++. I want to take user input on what file they want to play. But when I put the variable in PlaySound(); It gives me an error. Here is the code,

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter song name...\nMake sure the song is in the same folder as this program\n";
    string filename;
    getline(cin, filename);
    cout << "Playing song...\n";
    bool played = PlaySound(TEXT(filename), NULL, SND_SYNC);


    return 0;
}
```

Error,
`identifier "Lfilename" is undefined`
`'Lfilename': undeclared identifier`
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the error message(s) you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro with a variable, only with a compile-time character/string literal. You need to use the [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method instead.

Also, the fact that `TEXT()` is adding the `L` prefix to the specified identifier means you are compiling your project for Unicode (ie `UNICODE` is defined during preprocessing), which means `PlaySound()` (being a `TCHAR`-based macro itself) will map to `PlaySoundW()`, which expects a wide strong as input not a narrow string. So you need to call `PlaySoundA()` instead to match your use of `std::string`.

Try this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter song name...\nMake sure the song is in the same folder as this program\n";
    string filename;
    getline(cin, filename);
    cout << "Playing song...\n";
    bool played = PlaySoundA(filename.c_str(), NULL, SND_SYNC);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::wstring` instead, since Windows APIs prefer Unicode strings (ANSI-based APIs call the Unicode APIs internally):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    wcout << L"Enter song name...\nMake sure the song is in the same folder as this program\n";
    wstring filename;
    getline(wcin, filename);
    wcout << L"Playing song...\n";
    bool played = PlaySoundW(filename.c_str(), NULL, SND_SYNC);

    return 0;
}
```